# How to merge mutiple array in a single array

Tags: php, arrays, function, arraylist, multidimensional-array

As i searched alot but didn't get perfect solution of merging array in one single array.
These arrays are Dynamic (may be increase in future- would 50+). So for that we have to use `count()` or `for` `loops` to fetch and then merge.

Here's my code which i'm trying to resolve over core level. Please anyone tell me how may receive all values in Single array.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 108
        [2] => 58
        [3] => 23
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 93
        [1] => 94
        [2] => 95
        [3] => 172
        [4] => 30
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 109
        [1] => 81
        [2] => 79
        [3] => 155       )

)`
```

My expectation of result is: (which i'm unable to get)

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 108
    [2] => 58
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 93
    [5] => 94
    [6] => 95
    [7] => 172
    [8] => 30
    [9] => 109
    [10] => 81
    [11] => 79
    [12] => 155
)
```

Comment: Use `array_merge()`.

Comment: not even an attempt? you can even use the humble foreach in this case

Comment: what is your definition of "perfect solution"?

Comment: this was just a sample code of dynamic values coming from DB. please just let me know which technique is used to `merge` in `loop`

Comment: you already know that this won't scale well since you expect it to grow in the future so you should probably do the merging in the query itself and come up with a single row select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use array_merge with splat operator,

```
$result = array_merge(...$arr);
```

array_merge — Merge one or more arrays

[Splat operator](https://blog.programster.org/php-splat-operator) - [Since PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php), you can use splat operator (...) to create simpler [variadic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) (functions that take an undefined number of arguments).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/acdvF)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 108
    [2] => 58
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 93
    [5] => 94
    [6] => 95
    [7] => 172
    [8] => 30
    [9] => 109
    [10] => 81
    [11] => 79
    [12] => 155
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul .. this work for me.. thanks alot.. for making this quite simple.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Rahul this is so beautiful!, it's my first introduction with `array_merge(...$arr);` and splat operator. I'm going to implement this from now own. it's very convenient. Thank you

Comment: @freeek I know I faced the same too ;)

Comment: wow, didn't know splat operator supported in php. thx @Rahul !

Answer (score 1):

using `array_merge()`

```
$a[0] = [1,2,3];
$a[1] = [4,5,6];
$a[2] = [7,8,9];
$newArr = [];

$newArr = array_merge($a[0], $a[1], $a[2]);
print_r($newArr);
```

assuming that your array will grow, you can use foreach like this :

```
$a[0] = [1,2,3];
$a[1] = [4,5,6];
$a[2] = [7,8,9];
$newArr = [];

foreach($a as $index){
   foreach($index as $item){
      array_push($newArr, $item);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i used this technique. I got my answer in just a simple way. of `array_flatten`

```
print_r(array_flatten($overall_arr)); 


function array_flatten($array) {
$return = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)){
        $return = array_merge($return, array_flatten($value));
    } else {
        $return[$key] = $value;
    }
}
return $return;
}
```